# About Property not found Xcode 5 error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Here InformacionViewController.h:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "LibrosFenomenales.h"

 @interface InformacionViewController : UIViewController

 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nombre;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *autor;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *año;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *genero;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *argumento;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *portada;
 @property LibrosFenomenales *libroSeleccionado;

 @end
```

Here ViewController.m:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

   InformacionViewController *informacionViewController = [self.storyboard        
   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InformacionViewController"];
   UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]   
   initWithRootViewController:informacionViewController];

   informacionViewController.libroSeleccionado = [_libros objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Xcode shows me this error: Property "libroSeleccionado" not found on object of type "InformacionViewController".

This is the line: **informacionViewController.libroSeleccionado = [_libros objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];**

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try deleting derived data and restarting Xcode.

Comment: same error im getting :\

Comment: Finnally tried 2 times to clean all and works!!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Quiting the Xcode you just First clean the build. To clean the build Press command+Shift+K. then run the application even then If it doesn't work for then try this @property (strong, nonatomic) LibrosFenomenales *libroSeleccionado;
instead of @property LibrosFenomenales *libroSeleccionado;

Comment: That would be a comment to question not an answer. -1 for that

Comment: Eh. That's probably the answer.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, Lloyd, but I added your origin answer too. One of the two probably covers this.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without having access to the whole code, but try these:

- If "LibrosFenomenales" is an Objective-C class, change the property declaration to:

  `@property (strong, nonatomic) LibrosFenomenales *libroSeleccionado;`
- If the **LibrosFenomenales.h** header imports the **InformacionViewController.h** header, you have a cross-referencing issue. To fix this, open up **InformacionViewController.h** and replace:

  `#import "LibrosFenomenales.h"`

  by:

  `@class LibrosFenomenales;`;

  then open up **InformacionViewController.m** and add the `#import "LibrosFenomenales.h"` to it.
- Don't forget to `#import "InformacionViewController.m"` in **ViewController.m**

Comment: I'm reading about this ebook -> [link](https://itunes.apple.com/es/book/ios-7-development-is-phenomenal/id802982063?mt=11)